# Installing/ running a program from a zip file

Tags: software-installation

The creator of a favourite writing tool, Write Or Die, has released a linux version version of the latest edition (found at writeordie.com). In the zip I've downloaded, there is a WriteorDie2 folder. It contains:

```
\libffmpegsumo.so  nw.pak  WriteorDie2
```

(as listed by a dir in terminal)

WriteorDie2 already has the executable bit set, but trying to run it as a program gets me nothing. So, am I missing some jiggery pokery here? I'm a 64 bit install, and have downloaded the 64 bit version. I usually install things from a friendly deb file, so I'm a little lost.

Comment: I'm guessing you already unzipped the file. Normally included is some type of read me file explicitly tell you how to run the program.

Comment: Sadly lacking in this case. My first impulse as well, and as I like the developer I have already sent mail suggesting such. So far all the help the site gives is "If you can run Chrome, you should be able to run this."

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem. I attempted to run it via:

```
./WriteorDie2
```

And then got something about libudev.so.0 cannot open shared object file.

Did some searching and found some jiggery-pokery and attempted this:

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0
```

Then went back to my WoD2 folder and attempted to run the program again. I can run the program now, but all it does is bring up the Node-Webkit page (it won't let me post the picture) but nothing else, and I don't know what to do from there.

So that's about it for me right now. Maybe this will help us both get a little farther forward?